# How can I change the following code from pytorch to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I want to change the follow pytorch network (v1.2) to tensorflow. I am confusing between ***tf.nn.conv2d*** and ***tf.keras.layers.Conv2D*** what should I choose?

```
import torch.nn as nn  
nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, dilation=dilation, bias=True), 
    nn.BatchNorm2d(out_planes), 
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
```

Answer (score 3):

`tf.nn.conv2d` is functional api and `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` is layer-class api. You should use the latter one. It's quite as similar as the relationship between `torch.nn.functional.conv2d` and `torch.nn.Conv2D`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=10, kernel_size=3, strides=1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ReLU())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization

model = Sequential(
        [
            Conv2D(filters=10, kernel_size=3, strides=1)
            BatchNormalization()
            ReLU()
        ]
)
```